# sql get row with max date and relative id record

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I try to make a simple query, spent on it a tone of hours and get nothing....
All I need is to get MAX date and all is corresponding fields.

I'm explain:
I have a table with this fields: `BasketID`, `OrderStatusTypeID`, `StatusDate`.
I try to get only one record that contain `OrderStatusTypeID` value with the last `StatusDate`.

**This is the data**

```
BasketID    OrderStatusTypeID   date
1111        13              2013-04-01 11:38:31
1111        26              2013-04-04 17:44:17
1111        39              2013-04-02 12:35:07
1111        40              2013-04-08 12:52:55
```

**This is my query:**

```
SELECT BasketID, OrderStatusTypeID, max(StatusDate) date
FROM st
where BasketID=1111
group by BasketID
```

**This is the results i need**

```
BasketID    OrderStatusTypeID   date
63558       40          2013-04-08 12:52:55
```

For some reason I only get `OrderStatusTypeID = 13` and not `40`!
(max of StatusDate, and NOT max of OrderStatusTypeID).
Why???

```
BasketID    OrderStatusTypeID   date
63558       13                   2013-04-08 12:52:55
```

**Thanks for fast response!**

Comment: Your query doesn't even compile. What is your DBMS?

Comment: I think you can do that by `SELECT TOP 1 * From Table ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: pick the correct answer please... it will help to others also

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using `MySQL` because you can run the query even if you have not specified all the non-aggregate column in the `GROUP BY` clause.

There are many ways to solve the problem but I'm used to do it this way. The query uses a subquery which separately gets the latest `date` for every `BasketID`. Since the subquery returned only two columns, you need to join it back on the table itself to get the other columns provided that it match on two columns: `BasketID`, `Date`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    st a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  BasketID, MAX(Date) max_date
            FROM    st
            GROUP   BY BasketID
        ) b ON  a.BasketID = b.BasketID AND
                a.Date = b.max_date
```

Your query has executed successfully without throwing an exception even though there are non-aggregate columns that are not specified in the `GROUP BY` clause because it is permitted in MySQL. See [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Comment: Grate!
Thank you for extremely fast response!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but
why isn't it possible to use ORDER BY and LIMIT in this case?
A query like that:

SELECT * FROM st
WHERE BasketID=1111
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy to use TOP command like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM st 
WHERE BasketID = 1111
ORDER BY date DESC
```